# Implementing INDEX field in the context of a Primary Key and auto-incrementing int

Tags: mysql

I's been mentioned I need and auto-incrementing id to keep track of unique records...
...basically...a PRIMARY KEY pointing to an auto-incrementing int

I can kind of see this as user data is mutable..it changes...if you give each row an ID it serves as a way to track the user better and does not take up too much space - 4 bytes.

I've also heard that the INDEX field is used as a way to do speed up searches..

If I have a set of user attributes say, `A1, A2, A3`, and I have a Primary Key, P, defined as an int I...how does an INDEX relate to this?..i.e. how do I implement it properly?

Columns -

```
int, varchar, varchar, varchar,....Primary Key, Index ?

I, A1, A2, A3..., P, ?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In MySQL:

- the primary key is an index
- the AUTO_INCREMENT column must be the primary key
- KEY is a synonym of INDEX

So in your example `I` would be declared thus

```
CREATE TABLE (
  I int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  ...
  PRIMARY KEY (I)
  ...
```

However, this is a "surrogate" key because it isn't the natural key (eg Employee Number) so you'd have a unique index (or key) on that too

```
CREATE TABLE (    ...
  EmployeeNumber char(7) NOT NULL,
  ...
  UNIQUE KEY (EmployeeNumber)
  ...
```

Other indexes would be created on individual columns or combinations of columns based on use in JOINs and WHERE, but indexing strategies in general is separate to choosing a primary key for your table.

Comment: O.K so if I define something as  Primary Key I can rest assured that when I do a search on it..that the seach is efficient..i.e. that the data is put into a B tree as descrribed here - http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-indexes.html

Comment: I don't want to use a surrogate key...just wan to use your first example..is this O.K.?

Comment: Yes, at the top I said "the primary key is an index". And this *is* a surrogate key that is used for efficiency over a natural key. But yes, use my first example

Comment: thanks...it is easier than I thought..I just declare a column as a PRIMARY KEY and not it will be checked for uniqueness...+ I know that I only have one Primary Key

Comment: Not sure what you mean, but a Primary key will check uniqueness

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you have a 1:M relationship, in that a user can have many attributes. I would recommend a 2nd table storing the attributes with a foreign key back to the user table:

```
create table `user` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned not null auto_increment,
  `first_name` varchar(60) not null,
  primary key (`id`)
)engine=InnoDB default charset=utf8;

create table `user_attribute_link` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned not null auto_increment,
  `user_id` int(11) unsigned not null,
  `attribute_id` int(11) unsigned not null,      
  primary key (`id`),
  index (`user_id`, `attribute_id`),
  foreign key (`user_id`) references `user` (`id`) on delete cascade
  foreign key (`attribute_id`) references `user_attribute` (`id`) on delete cascade
 )engine=InnoDB default charset=utf8;

create table `user_attribute` (
    `id` int(11) unsigned not null auto_increment,
    `name` varchar(60) not null,
    primary key (`id`),
    unique key (`name`),
)engine=InnoDB default charset=utf8;
```

The FK from the user table to the user_attribute table will ensure if you delete a row from user, any child rows from user_attribute will also be deleted. Unique key was also added to the attribute table to ensure you aren't able to add any dupe attributes.

**EDIT**
Updated the schema with a 3rd table supporting a M:M (via 1:M - M: 1). This will allow for more flexibility if you need to add more info to user attributes.

Comment: This gets ugly if attributes have different types because it becomes an EAV http://karwin.blogspot.com/2009/05/eav-fail.html or http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/93124/eav-is-is-really-bad-in-all-scenarios

Comment: @gbn: Agreed, offered a solution based on the OP, but I updated the schema to support flexibility to user attributes.